# Double bottom-border for shading

Tags: css

```
.sitemapml li db {
 border-bottom: medium dotted #36383b;
 z-index: -1;
 left: 1px;
 bottom: -4px;
 position: relative;
 width: 230px;
}
.sitemapml li {
    border-bottom: medium dotted #888b8e;
    width: 230px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    z-index: 600;
}
```

I'm trying to use this in order to shade the dotted seperator in a menulist, the problem is, that the dots are in place ok, but not to the proper 230px width. i.e its set to the A Href inside width.. I changed the a href width to 230px too.. but the dots still remain under the words HOME only..

Comment: Is it possible for you to put jsfiddle link

Comment: just curious...what is a `<db>`?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9zqS7/

Comment: I just used db as Double Border as I have no idea how to go round this NO Double border thingy.

Comment: db isn't a known tag.

Comment: changed it to <div id="dborder"></div> that should do the trick :) thanks jay :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though I'm not sure what a `<db>` tag is, you mention the `A Href inside width`, so I am assuming you are trying to use an `<a href="#">` tag.

Anchor tags are inline elements, not block elements. Because of this, they will only use the width of their contained text, rather than the pixel dimensions you set.

You will need to add `display: block` to your Anchor style. This will change it to use your 230px width.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jayharris/sEL8H/)

Comment: by doing the display: block, the cursor is no longer showing as pointer, is it due the block addition?

Comment: No. That is due to `position: relative`. See the updated JSFiddle.

Comment: is it normal for a link to be like that as in the jsfiddle, the cursor keeps on going for the width of the border? or is that abug?

Comment: That's the `display: block` on the Anchor tag. The Tag takes the full width because it's needed to get the border to be the full width.

Comment: To change, wrap the anchor tag in another tag, like a DIV. And apply the second border to that. Note that if you use a DIV, which is already a block-level element, you will no longer need `display: block`